# Non-point \divideontimes?

Tags: math-operators, text

Is there a non-point `\divideontimes`?

Note: It does not `\asterisk`.

Is there anyone to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\newcommand{\minusontimes}{\mathbin{\mathrlap{\times}-}}
\begin{document}
$\minusontimes$
$\divideontimes$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean this. Good working.